# JSF calling methods in JPA populated list

Tags: jsf, jpa, methods

I have a database table with some oneToMany relations. 
this is fragment of the entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="auction")
private List<Biding> bidings;
```

now i want to print higher bid on my jsf website:

```
<ui:repeat var="singleAuction" value="#{auctionListBean.auctionList}"  varStatus="status">
<h:outputLabel value="#{singleAuction.getHigherBid()}"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

this my aucListBean

```
    @ManagedBean
    public class AuctionListBean 
    {
        @PersistenceContext()
        EntityManager entityManager;

        public List<AuctionBean> getAuctionList() {
            Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Auction e");
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<AuctionBean> resultList = (List<AuctionBean>) query.getResultList();
            return resultList;
        }
    }
```

I also have AuctionBean class which I used before to add new auction. Now I want to create a bean which has one property: list of auctionBean. I populate it using my entity and cast it to AuctionBean. In AuctionBean class I implemented mentioned method:

```
public double getHigherBid()
    {
        double higherBid = 0;
        for(Biding a : bidings)
        {
            if(a.getCurrentPrice() > higherBid) 
                higherBid = a.getCurrentPrice();
        }
        return higherBid;
    }
```

The problem is "Method not found". It seems like it still dont even use AuctionBean class for some reason. It may be a problem why it cannot see the method. I am doing it right and where is the problem exactly? Could you help?

Comment: Please, copypaste the exact exception and full stack trace unmodified in the question instead of overgeneralizing it as "problem". The exception and full stack trace are very important because they are the whole answer at its own! That you're unable to read/interpret them doesn't mean what you can ignore it as if it's decoration.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions:
1. Use singleAuction.higherBid, not singleAuction.getHigherBid()
2. Specify the target class of your query. Here's an example:

```
return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Auction e", AuctionBean.class)
    .getResultList();
```